Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x_{2n} + x_{2n+1})$ converges.
The following is exercise 2.5.4 (a) from Basic Analysis I, by Jiri Lebl:

Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x_{2n} + x_{2n+1})$ converges.

This is for my brother's homework. When I initially looked at this problem, my first thought was that if we were given the series was absolutely convergent, then the problem becomes much easier to solve. However, we are not given that here.
One strategy I had in mind was to cover the two possible cases:
(1) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ is absolutely convergent, or
(2) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ is conditionally convergent, but not absolutely convergent.
But doing it this way would require using Riemann's rearrangement theorem for the second case (which I don't even know will help).
Does anyone have suggestions on the best way to approach this problem?

Any subsequence of converged sequence converges.

Look at the partial sums $S_k := \sum_{n=1}^k (x_{2n} + x_{2n+1})$. We have $S_1 = x_2 + x_3$, $S_2 = x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = \sum_{n=2}^5 x_n$, $S_3 = \sum_{n=2}^7 x_n$, $\dots$. Using this with the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges should lead you somewhere.
